# ruby on rails validation regex comma separated email addresses

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to regex and need to parse a comma-separated input of email address extensions (everything after the @ symbol).  Example:

foo.bar,foo.bar.baz,foo-bar.baz

I know that there are no whitespaces in the string. Also. following is the regex I want to use for just a single email extension:

```
/[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

How do I modify the regex in Ruby to work with multiple extensions which are comma separated?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Can you give an example of the input and the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better of splitting the list into components and then checking each component:

```
hosts  = 'foo.bar,foo.bar.baz,foo-bar.baz'
all_ok = true
hosts.split(/\s*,\s*/).each do |host|
    all_ok = false unless(host =~ /[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i)
end
```

That may not be a one-liner but it will probably be a lot easier to understand six months down the road (unless, of course, your regex-fu gets stronger).

Comment: Thanks! However, I am writing some test cases and I think my original regex is a little faulty. Things like foo|bar.org is passing. I think the reason is because it is matching the "bar.org". Not a regex expert, but is there a way to fail unless it successfully matches the ENTIRE thing?

Comment: You need to anchor your regex at both ends (rather than just the end) to take care of "foo|bar.org", something more like `/\A[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i`. Maybe a bit of time at [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) would be fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

```
\A(([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})[, ]?)*\Z
```

The above regular expression works for 0 or more number of email addresses separated b commas. You may like to chomp (",") the string before saving or using it to remove the trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

try

`/(,{0,1}[a-zA-Z_]+[^.]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/i`

based on my test:

`p 'True' if 'foo.bar,foo.bar.baz,foo-bar.baz' =~ /(,{0,1}[a-zA-Z_]+[^.]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/i`

will give

`True`